# How to calculate means of other columns based on one column data if I want that data to be in specific range

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I am a beginner and currently doing a data analysis project and would like to know if its possible to filter one column data and find the means of other columns based on that filtration?

Right now I have this

```
means = df.groupby('popularity').mean()
```

but I would like to get only those means if the popularity is greater than 95.

It ranges from 0 to 97 and right now the code shows me all of the means of different columns based on popularity column.

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple ways to do this
You can try filtering.

```
df.loc[df['Popularity'] >= 95].groupby(['Popularity']).mean()
```

That oughta return your full dataset and do the same grouped operation but filtered according to your condition

```
df.loc[df['Popularity'] >= 95].groupby(['Popularity']).transform(np.mean)
```

Oughta return a series of the mean values not sure which one you want so here is both